# jQuery .on('click') don't work

Tags: jquery, laravel, onclick, click

I really don't know why it's not working, I have a simple jQuery click function :

```js
 $('.pagination a').on('click', function(e){
        console.log("test");
        e.preventDefault();
        var url = $(this).attr('href');
        $.post(url, function(data){
            $('#disponibilite_table').html(data);
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <ul role="navigation" class="pagination">
    <li class="page-item">
        <a href="http://localhost/codeurProject/public/admin?page=1" rel="prev" aria-label="« Previous" class="page-link waves-effect waves-effect">‹</a>
   </li>
  </ul>
```

But nothing, and I really don't know why ...

Comment: Check the snippet in the question. What is not working?

Comment: The click event is not triggered, when I click on the <a> I have the default Laravel thing but not my jQuery function (the "test" is not showing in the console)

Comment: But your code works above. I can see `test` in `console` @Jessy

Comment: In my Laravel app no one of the .on('click') i try works ... is this a Laravel problem ? I always have to put onclick("myfunctioon...") to my element, but in this case I can't :/

Comment: In your app, add `console.log($('.pagination a').length)` - what do you get in the console?

Answer (score 0):

Change :

```
$('.pagination a').onClick(function(e){
    console.log("test");
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    $.post(url, function(data){
        $('#disponibilite_table').html(data);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the script after the ul.

```
<ul role="navigation" class="pagination">
    <li class="page-item">
        <a href="http://localhost/codeurProject/public/admin?page=1" rel="prev" aria-label="« Previous" class="page-link waves-effect waves-effect">‹</a>
    </li>
</ul>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The script is running before the tag you query for is ever created so the query $(.pagination a) returns with no results and the listener is never registered

Comment: The script is after, but I found a solution, when i embed my script in a document.ready function this works